# Just how much "heavier" might be Ubuntu 18 when switch to Gnome3?

Tags: unity, gnome

I recently updated my old laptop from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

I looked into the recommended system requirements of 16.04.2 (& 17.04 which are the same)- and found they are spot on my laptop's specs. I know that "recommended" is not "minimal" so I'll be good on those two upgrades.

My question is, I read that Ubuntu 18 will switch Unity for Gnome3 - which is heavier on system use (?), How much heavier? will my old laptop hold or do I need to switch OS /get a "new" (refurbished)laptop?

Processor Intel core2 duo CPU U7700 1.33 GHZ x2
System memory 2 GB 
32 bit
Over 50 GB available on hard drive (out of 80GB)

Comment: Any answer about Ubuntu 18.04 will be conjecture. Specs change between releases. Maybe someone finds a couple of tweaks that makes it CPU friendlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can always switch DE if you don't like the default one. Perhaps even to the Unity *(although the gist is that Canonical gonna move development resources out of Unity, but may be community step in)*.

On the topic: AFAIK Gnome is heavier on GPU, which you didn't mention ☺  Also looking the benchmarks [from 14 April 2017](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-1704-desks&num=1) Unity is a tiny bit faster than Gnome *(make sure to read the text too — the first benchmark, where Gnome looked like performed terribly, have had a technical problem)*. Also note that I am not using Gnome myself *(I am on i3)*, but I've occasionally saw on IRC people complained about lags in some of Gnome menus. If you see the same: this is irrelevant to GPU, and is a bug which hopefully be*(was?)* fixed.

But that's about short-term. In the long-term, of course, Gnome is/will be refactored, improved, etc — so I'm sure its performance will get better. The more that after Canonical have officially switched to Gnome, Gnome would be developed by at least Canonical and Red Hat. You can peek at development for [gnome-shell](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/log/) and [mutter](https://git.gnome.org/browse/mutter/log/) *(the WM)*.

Overall performance-wise it's always worth upgrading the system. E.g. by using 14.04 you're [limiting yourself to mesa 10.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mesa&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) which is terribly outdated. Last bugfix release *(not even features)* for 10.1 was June 24, 2014, and last bugfix release for whole 10 series *(the 10.6, to be specific)* at October 3, 2015. Although in 2016/2017 there were a bunch of cool improvements, both CPU and GPU wise, in graphics drivers.

Same for the kernel: [3.13 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) — that sounds like a bad joke! As of writing the words latest kernel is 4.12. Just [skim through releases here](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions) to see how much improvements you're missing. New IO and power governors, improvements to file systems, drivers, core, memory management, network sybsystems, overall refactoring, atomic changes to GPU drivers… You're really missing a lot of performance improvements.